# md-select with recursive options

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-material

I am trying to iterate through an array of categories with subcategories.

The problem. I have this array of categories:

```
$scope.categories = [{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Cat 1",
  "categories": {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "Cat 11",
    "categories": {
      "_id": 111,
      "name": "Cat 111",
      "categories": null
    }
  }
}, {
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Cat 2",
  "categories": null
}, {
  "_id": 3,
  "name": "Cat 3",
  "categories": null
}];
```

As you can see, is an array of objects with subcategories, so I know that I need a recursive solution.

I need to show all the categories into a md-select (it is not necesary group it, but it will be great) and I am trying this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Categories</label>
  <md-select ng-model="selectedCategory">
    <md-option ng-value="category._id" ng-repeat-start="category in categories">{{category.name}}</md-option>
    <span ng-repeat-end ng-include="'subcategories'" ng-if="category.categories"></span>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="subcategories">
{{category.name}}
<md-option ng-value="category._id" ng-repeat-start="category in category.categories">{{category.name}}</md-option>
<span ng-repeat-end ng-include="'subcategories'" ng-if="category.categories"></span>
```

It works partially, but it is not the result expected.

What I want? Something like this

[image]

What I have? [This code](https://plnkr.co/edit/IrHeM1MJQwXhjSNz8iNc?p=preview)

Tell me if need more details.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's angularjs question not angular

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply flatten your list and style elements by their nesting level.

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppController', function($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [{
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Cat 1",
      "categories": [{
        "_id": 11,
        "name": "Cat 11",
        "categories": [{
          "_id": 111,
          "name": "Cat 111",
          "categories": null
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "Cat 2",
      "categories": null
    }, {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "Cat 3",
      "categories": null
    }];

    $scope.flattenCategories = flatten($scope.categories, 0);

    function flatten(categories, level) {
      var flat = [];
      for (var i = 0, n = categories.length, category; category = categories[i]; i++) {
        flat.push({
          _id: category._id,
          name: category.name,
          level: level
        });
        if (category.categories) {
          flat = flat.concat(flatten(category.categories, level + 1));
        }
      }

      return flat;
    }

  });
```

```css
.subcategory-0 .md-text {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.subcategory-1 .md-text {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.subcategory-2 .md-text {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.subcategory-3 .md-text {
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Categories</label>
      <md-select ng-model="selectedCategory" name="myCategory">
        <md-option ng-class="'subcategory-' + category.level" ng-value="category._id" ng-repeat="category in flattenCategories track by category._id">{{ category.name }}</md-option>
      </md-select>
      <!-- <pre ng-bind="flattenCategories | json"></pre> -->
    </md-input-container>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be a `optgroup` I think instead of `md-option`!